# Google Analytics alternatives?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Can you suggest any Google Analytics alternatives? What are you using on your sites?

UA analytics now changed to GA4, so looking alternative...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a **technical perspective**, if you're looking for a **free solution**, you can use:

- [Yandex Metrica](https://metrica.yandex.com/about?), very powerful but very intrusive (session replay).
- [Matomo](https://matomo.org/) (previously Piwik), which can be self hosted.
- [Statscounter](https://statcounter.com/). Its free plan let you analyze the latest 500 page views.

I have been using all three in the past but I renounced to any analytics.

There are also tons of paid solutions.

---

**Some factors to consider**

1. How much are you ready to sacrify the privacy of your visitors by sharing their web browsing with third-parties?
2. Which features / level of detail will you need and with what purpose? Will analytics lead you to more informed choices?
3. Is the time that you invest in analytics worth it, or would possibly the same time be invested more usefully in improving user experience by trusting your intuition?
4. Do you want to own your stats and are you ready for some possible maintenance (Matomo) or are you looking for an external hosted solution?
5. How much are you ready to slower your website with the tracking that analytics involves?